# How to show that an ideal is not principal in a generic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals, ideal-class-group

Suppose I'm trying to calculate the class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{29})$, such as in [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381991/how-does-assuming-grh-help-us-calculate-class-group).  It is noted that Magma calculates the class group to be $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ very quickly, by looking at primes up to $826$.

What does the computer need in order to be sure that a given ideal is NOT principal?  To show an ideal IS principal, a generator will do, and if you have a set of representatives for the classes of the class group, you can certifiably equate any other ideal to one of the classes by finding a generator of the quotient by one of the classes.  But what certificate do you need to prove that a given ideal is NOT principal?

For totally complex fields, it should be easy: the norm polynomial is "definite", in that there are only finitely many linear combinations of the generators of the integer ring that have norm less than any given $N$, because it can be written as the sum of squares.  So a finite calculation can be done.

For real quadratic fields, for an ideal $I$, we can find verification for some $n$ that $I^n=(\alpha)$ is principal, and then if $I$ itself were principal it would be generated by $\beta$ whose $n$th power was $\pm\alpha\cdot\varepsilon^k$ where $\varepsilon$ is the fundamental unit for some $k$ between $0$ and $n-1$.  Then taking rational and surd parts of $\beta^n=\pm\alpha\cdot\varepsilon^k$ gives $2k$ systems of $2$ equations in $2$ variables which we can solve, and thus verify that it is not principal.

So can we extend this reasoning?  Is there another general-purpose method to prove that a given ideal is not principal?

Comment: For real quadratic fields we can use any unit (not a root of unity) to find an upper bound for $\inf \{ \|\alpha \|,\alpha \in O_K,N(\alpha)=p\}$ where $\|\alpha\|=\sum_j |\sigma_j(\alpha )|$ , then (given a $\Bbb{Z}$-basis of $O_K$) we can enumerate the elements with $\|.\|$ lower than this bound.  I think the same works in any number field thanks to Dirichlet's unit theorem.

Comment: The same method works in general number fields if you happen to know a full system of independent units.